# why i am not able to use MPI_Scatter() in the scope of a particular process?

Tags: c++, c, memory, scope, mpi

I know , there is no concept/meaning of global variables when dealing with openMpi and hence when a particular thread is changing a variable ,the value of the variable will still set to be as default in other processes.
I know the functionality of MPI_Scatter().

When i use something like this ,

```
1.   if(rank==0) {

     //call to MPI_Scatter()

      MPI_Scatter(data,8,MPI_FLOAT,pdata,4,
                    MPI_FLOAT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    }
```

From this code , each process(4) is supposed to receive 8 float numbers in array pdata.
but the thing happening is only the root process(the one which have the one containing MPI_Scatter ) is receiving and others are still having the initial value in pdata.

```
2.  if(rank==0) {
   //create a buffer to be used in the MPI_Scatter which will be called outside the socpe
  FOR(i,0,16) {
       data[i]=i ;
  }
}

MPI_Scatter(data,8,MPI_FLOAT,pdata,4,
                    MPI_FLOAT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Since data[] is a global variable, the value must not be accessible from other processes .still in this case i am able to accomplish this in a perfect way.

Explanation of these two points in terms of memory structure will be highly useful .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, *all* processes must call `MPI_Scatter` for it to work "as advertised."  In your code, only the root process is calling it.

Comment: that was quite obvious , i was expecting a more detailed answer . Thanks for giving time .

Comment: Sorry, there's not alot more detail to give.  If the receiving processes don't call that routine, they will simply never go through the steps needed to receive the data, and "memory structure" will be beside the point.  You say this is obvious, but after I re-read your question, it still sounds to me like you initially did not understand the issue.  Maybe I misunderstood.  Maybe you want to edit your question?

Comment: I agree with @bob.sacamento here. It's hard to understand from your question what you're asking for. Before anything else can be discussed, the question has to be valid.

Comment: now i feel satisfied and used to with this convention .thanks. Further i want to ask the way in which i want to scatter the data (suppose the data is generated in root process) such that the root process shouldn't have data received from the scattering . Hope you got my point . Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ankur Gautam: I think in this case what you want to do is have the root process to call MPI_Send (or some variant thereof), once for each destination process, and have each destination process call MPI_Recv (or some variant thereof).  Some clever person out there may be able to figure out a more efficient way, but that's what comes to my mind.

Comment: Thanks @bob.sacamento  would you like to answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17349703/difference-between-clock-and-mpi-wtime