# Non-MPI program with mpirun slower with multiple cores

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmpi

I have the below non-MPI program for computing the average of a random vector, each parallel process generating a different random vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector> 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

 clock_t begin = clock();
 size_t N(10000000);
 double avg(0.0);
 int ID(atoi(argv[1]));

 //Random seed for each process
 srand(time(NULL) + ID);

 std::vector<int> v1(N);

 for(size_t n=0; n<N; n++) {
  v1[n] = rand() % 100;
  avg += v1[n]/double(N);
 }

 clock_t end = clock();

 std::cout<<"Process "<<ID<<": Average = "<<avg<<std::endl;
 std::cout<<"Process "<<ID<<": Time taken = "<<double(end -     begin)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<" seconds"<<std::endl;

 return 0;

}
```

I compile the program with g++4.8, and run it with

```
 mpirun -np N bash -c './test.exe $OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK'
```

For a single process (N=1), i.e. not parallelised, I get the output

```
Process 0: Average = 49.5008
Process 0: Time taken = 0.295664 seconds
```

whereas using two processes (N=2) each process takes longer:

```
Process 0: Average = 49.5007
Process 0: Time taken = 0.565198 seconds
Process 1: Average = 49.4963
Process 1: Time taken = 0.565898 seconds
```

Binding to core with N=2 still makes one of the processes as fast as the N=1 case but the other process is still slow. I have a 4-core machine.

Is there some race condition here (I don't see why though)? What am I missing?

Comment: This -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17349703/difference-between-clock-and-mpi-wtime -- is one of the many SO Qs and As on the topic of measuring the time of program execution.  It is, I think, relevant to your question.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: That's indeed good to know. Even so I can palpably tell that the multi-core execution of my actual program (and not just, but also, the above MWE) takes longer as the number of processors are increased. Whereas I would have expected the same execution time if the entire code is simply being run on a separate processor (which presumably also avoids any race condition)?

Comment: I don't understand how you can get any accurate information unless you can control the delegation of tasks to cores.  For example, on a 2 core processor, the OS could delegate a music app to one core and your program to another core; thus you think your program is running on two cores when in fact it is only running on one core, time or code slicing.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: I face this issue also when running on dedicated nodes where I know no other applications are running. It's not clear to me what the best way to use `mpirun` is then i.e. to get _n_ instances of the non-MPI program to be run on a multicore environment without it taking _longer_ than a single run.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. On an i7-5820K CPU with SMT enabled, the program runtime stays around the same for up to 6 processes. What kind of CPU do you have and what is the output when you add `--report-bindings` to the list of `mpirun` arguments?