# OpenMPI: Parallel code executing slower than serial Code. Why?

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, openmpi

I have two simple codes:
One to compute PI
One to count the number of blank spaces in a file with less than 10.000 characters.

I made the serial code and the parallel code with OpenMPI.

When I run them and compared the running time in CPU using:

```
clock_t begin = clock();
```

The serial code goes much faster than the parallel code:

```
Serial code: 0.000234

OpenMPI with 2-nodes 0.005987
OpenMPI with 4-nodes 0.002890
OpenMPI with 8-nodes 0.015805
```

As you can see, the more nodes, the slower it goes.

I wish to understand why.

Here are the codes:

```
int main() {

clock_t begin = clock();

int file_size = 10000;
FILE * fp;
int my_size, my_id, size, local_acum=0, acum=0, i;
char buf[file_size], recv_vect[file_size];

fp = fopen("pru.txt","r");
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
size = ftell(fp);
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
fread (buf,1,size,fp);

// Initialize the MPI environment 
MPI_Init(NULL, NULL); 
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_size); 
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&my_id);

MPI_Scatter(buf, size / my_size, MPI_CHAR, recv_vect, 
    size / my_size, MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

local_acum=0;
for (i=0; i < size / my_size ; i++){
    if (recv_vect[i] == ' '){
        local_acum++;
    }
}

acum=0;
MPI_Reduce(&local_acum, &acum, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 
    0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if (my_id == 0){
    printf("Counter is %d \n", acum);
}

// Finalize the MPI environment. 
MPI_Finalize();

clock_t end = clock();

double run_time = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

printf("Final time %f \n", run_time);
}



//Serial code

int main() {

clock_t begin = clock();

FILE * fp;
int size;
char buf[10000];

/* read file “pru.txt” and store it in buf[] */
/* NOTE: file must be smaller than 10000 characters */
fp = fopen("pru.txt","r");
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
size = ftell(fp);
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
fread (buf,1,size,fp);

/* add the code to count number of spaces in buf[] */
int i =0; 
int acum=0; 
for (i=0; i<size; i++){
    if (buf[i] == ' ')
        acum++;
}
printf("Counter is %d \n", acum);

clock_t end = clock();

double run_time = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

printf("Final time %f \n", run_time);
}
```

My guess is that given the size of the problem, there is a overhead of splitting the data, sending it to the nodes, computing and them reducing to obtain a final result.

The issue is that the problem is so simple that parallel executing cannot overleap its overheads.

• Parallel task granularity;

• Communication overhead;

• Load balancing among processes.

Thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: Your guesses are probably in the right place.  But do yourself a favour and replace `clock` with a routine that is guaranteed to return 'wall-clock time' on your platform -- see 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17349703/difference-between-clock-and-mpi-wtime

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark   When I use time_t For the serial get I get running time 0!

Comment: 10k characters is probably too few to justify going parallel.  But try with 10M or 10G characters.